# Scraping info of a product that is spread among different <tr> elements?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm using something like the following to scrape the info of a page:

```
  def self.parse_products
    product_hash = {}
    product = @data.css('.simGrid')

    product.css('td').each do | product |
      product_asin = product.css('.simImage a img').first.value[/(?<=\/)[A-Z\d]{5,}/]
      product_image_url = product.css('.simProductInfo a').to_s
      product_hash[:product] ||= []
      product_hash[:product] << { :image_url        => product_image_url,
                                  :asin             => product_asin }
    end 

    product_hash
  end
```

The problem is that the structure is something like this:

```
<table class="simGrid">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="middle">
        <td>
          <div class="simImage"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="simImage"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="simImage"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="simProductInfo"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="simProductInfo"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="simProductInfo"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <hr class="divider" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <hr class="divider" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <hr class="divider" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="middle">
        <td>
          <div class="simImage"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="simImage"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="simImage"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="simProductInfo"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="simProductInfo"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="simProductInfo"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <hr class="divider" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <hr class="divider" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <hr class="divider" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>  
  </table>
```

So as you can see the info of the product is spread among various `<tr>`. If I try to scrape them by using `<td>` I end up with many `nil` values since some of the `<td>` have the `.simImage` and others don't. Same for the `.simProductInfo`.

As anyone encounter something similar before? Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can try collecting ASINs and URLs in two separate arrays and then zipping them.

```
asins = product.css('.simImage a img').map { |n| n.value[/(?<=\/)[A-Z\d]{5,}/] }
urls = product.css('.simProductInfo a').map(&:to_s)

asins.zip(urls).map { |asin, url| {image_url: url, asin: asin} }
```